# Copy Permission From Windows Based user To Local user

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to know if it is possible to copy the permissions of a windows user to a locally created user on SQL server?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. I guess you mean "Windows Login" and "SQL Server Login".
You can script permissions using system objects such as sys.database_permissions or using a tool such as [Idera SQL permissions extractor](http://www.idera.com/Free-Tools/SQL-permissions-extractor/).